# How to find the upper Riemann integral of following function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

$f(x)$ is defined on $[a,b]$ as -

$= 0$ if $x ∈ [a, b] ∩ Q$

$= x$ otherwise

Lower integral is $0$ and i think that upper integral should be $(b^2 - a^2)/2$(i may be wrong also) but i am not able to prove it.

Comment: Bound it above by a step function.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown after  solving that i get $<=$ inequality and not $=$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the irrationals are dense, we have $\sup_{x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x) = x_j$.

Hence, for **any** partition, $a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$, the upper Darboux sum is

$$U(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n x_j(x_j - x_{j-1})  = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n(x_j+x_{j-1})(x_j - x_{j-1}) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})(x_j - x_{j-1}) \\ = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^n(x_j^2 - x_{j-1}^2) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})^2 = \frac{b^2-a^2}{2} +  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})^2,  $$

Since the last term on the RHS is nonnegative we have, for the **upper integral**,
$$\overline{\int_a^b} f(x) \, dx = \inf_{P}U(P,f) \geqslant \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}$$

To prove we actually have  $\inf_{P}U(P,f) = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}$, we show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition such that

$$U(P,f) < \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2} + \epsilon$$

For a uniform partition where $x_j - x_{j-1} = \frac{b-a}{n}$ for $j=1,2, \ldots, n$ we have

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})^2 = \frac{1}{2} n\frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2} = \frac{(b-a)^2}{2n}$$

Now choose $n > \frac{(b-a)^2}{2\epsilon}$ and we have

$$\begin{align}U(P,f) &=\frac{b^2 - a^2}{2} +  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-x_{j-1})^2\\ &= \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}+ \frac{(b-a)^2}{2n}  \\&< \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2} + \epsilon\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\overline{\int_a^b} f(x) \, dx = \inf_{P}U(P,f) = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}$$

Comment: We can use the theorem that if $P_n$ is a sequence of partitions such that norm/mesh of $P_n$ tends to $0$ then $U(P_n, f) \to \overline{\int_{a} ^{b} }f(x) \, dx$ and then take $P_n$ as uniform partition. +1 as your answer proves this theorem for the given function.

Answer (score 0):

For any partition $a=x_0<x_1<\ldots <x_n=b$, the Riemann upper sum is
$$
U_{\mathbf x}=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\sup_{x_{i-1}<x<x_i}f(x)
$$
In each interval $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ there is some real numbers $r\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$ and hence the supremum is $\sup_{x_{i-1}<x<x_i}f(x)\ge f(x_{i-1})=x_{i-1}$.

Therefore 
$$
U_{\mathbf x}\ge \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})x_{i-1}
$$
Here to compute a bound, we can take any, easy to compute, subdivision. I take $x_i=a+\frac{(b-a)i}{n}=a+ih$

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})x_{i-1}&=h\sum_{i=1}^n(a+(i-1)h) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}h(2a+h(n-1))n \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(b-a)(2a+\frac{(b-a)(n-1)}{n})
\end{align}
With
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}(b-a)(2a+\frac{(b-a)(n-1)}{n})=\frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2)
$$
Hence you have your result,

- as $n\to\infty$, the upper bound is $U_x\ge\frac{1}{2}(b-a)^2$
- as upper bound is greater that lower bound, the function is **not** Riemann integrable

Comment: But how to prove that upper integral is equal to  $(b*b - a*a)/2$

Comment: it is upper bound when $n->\infty$, as described in the answer, is it ok or not?

Comment: but i want upper bound equal to $(b^2-a^2)/2$

Comment: read  question once again

Comment: i have to go right now, read it when back sorry. hold on

Comment: no problem. I will wait

Comment: @Amit back, sorry. I am not sure I understand well the question. To define Riemann integral, you use upper and lower bound (of the Riemann sums) and show that they have the same limit. In our case upper bound is minored by (b^2-a^2)/2 and lower bound is majored by 0, thus they can not have the same limit thus there is no Riemann integral. What I do not understand in your question is what is upper "integral" ? (I only undestand upper "bound" of the Riemann sum)

Comment: sorry, I think I have understood, you want upper bound = (b^2-a^2)/2 valid for any Riemann sum, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86486/discussion-between-amit-and-picaud-vincent).